# BlackBerry Push Service return rc=10002, what that means?

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

when i try to register to the Blackberry push service from the real device i receive this response from their server "rc=10002"and wont register to the service.

what this response means and why im getting this now (the same code was working fine at the same device and network).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code included in the API examples rc == 10002:

> The push application id specified is
>   null or empty or if the push
>   application with the given id cannot
>   be found.

Comment: Thanks, the App registration with BlackBerry was expired.